# Control thermostat capillary failure reason why?

Tags: thermostat, appliances, oven

The problem I have is the temperature goes way too high on the electric oven - this is a new oven that failed on the first day that I am now stuck with.

I diagnosed it to the control thermostat.

As an attempt to trying to figure out the exact reason for this fault, I dissembled most of it.

There doesn't seem to be anything I can point to as the problem.

It doesn't seem adjustable. The capillary tube/sensor goes from inside the oven to the control thermostat and winds underneath. I assume under normal conditions when this tube heats up it expands on the other end which pushes internal switch/contact to the open position, thereby switching off the connection to the heat element.

Could this issue really be the capillary tube and I have no choice but to purchase an expensive replacement thermostat? I don't see anything else within the thermostat control that could be causing the issue.

Thanks

Comment: why is it not covered by warranty?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the capillary tube. it was broken at one point.

Answer (score 0):

These themostats are extremely sophisticated. It is doubtful a layman could recognize the failure if he were staring right at it.  If the oven overheats/ runs-away and you see no obvious wiring problems then you have little choice but replace the stat itself.  If it is any consolation those units are typically reliable. There are available universal replacement oven thermostats; typically for considerably less.  Good Luck.

Comment: Paul, this thermostat was actually fairly simple. there are no electronic components here. all it takes is a reverse engineering mindset to take any complex system apart. this was not complex at all but I admit it was a little tricky to put back together. anyhow, the thermostat needs to be replaced because it's welded on internally to a proprietary part within the thermostat that engages and disengages the contacts which is spring loaded. so the capillary tube renders the entire thermostat garbage, which is sad.